# Is there something similar as SqlBulkCopy in VBA (Excel)?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, vba, sqlbulkcopy

In C# I use System.Data.SqlClient and do something like code below. Is there something similar in VB (Excel)?

```
    { static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable csvData) 

            string connetionString = null; 
            SqlConnection cnn; 
            connetionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Import"].ConnectionString;

        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString); 
            cnn.Open(); 
            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(cnn)) 
            { 
                s.DestinationTableName = "dbo.MyTable"; 
                foreach (var column in csvData.Columns) 
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString()); 
                s.WriteToServer(csvData); 
            }
```

I try export data from my table from Excel to SQL Server. I can't use bulk insert, because the file is on different machine, so SQL can't read it.

So more, I tried make something like this in VB (Excel):

```
Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fieldIndex As Long
Dim rowIndex As Long
Set recSet = New ADODB.Recordset
Sqlstr = "Select * from MyTable"
recSet.Open Sqlstr, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic


     For rowIndex = 2 To 10000
                recSet.AddNew
                    For fieldIndex = 1 To 9
                 recSet.Fields(Cells(1, fieldIndex).Value) = Replace(Sheets("MyTable").Cells(rowIndex, fieldIndex).Value, ",", ".")
                Next fieldIndex
    Next rowIndex
    recSet.UpdateBatch
```

But there are thousands of rows and each row is inserted to SQL by own INSERT statement. This takes a lot of time and server's resources. Is it possible to optize this?

Comment: Do you have the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider installed on SQL Server? Use a SQL query to read the data into the table.

Comment: You could expose a COM-visible API for it, written in C# - it would intake an array with the table metadata, another array with the data, and a connection string; from there the C# code could create the `DataTable`, open the connection, and leverage `SqlBulkCopy`. ADODB predates .NET 2.0 (the class didn't exist in .NET 1.1) by quite a few years.

Comment: If you have access to SQL Server Management Studio, you could also use the "Import Data" feature to read from your Excel table as a data source.

Comment: How come you don't just use the c# version? You seem to already have it, and visual studio is free...

Comment: @WEI_DBA, after installation Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is maybe a little bit better, but still not as fast as I Want :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon this is the way that I am considering, but I thought maybe there is something in VBA that I don't know about.

Comment: @DeadZone I know, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem, I wanted to give it to a person who can't have access to the Management Studio

Comment: @CaiusJard this is intended for the user who can easily count and save something. Excel is the interface for calculations. But maybe this is the only way in this case.

Comment: Have you looked at SSIS?

Comment: TBH the ideal solution is to have the user dump the correctly-formatted file in a network share that the SQL Server instance can access, and then implement an ETL process that loads the data from there - SSIS is an option, plain T-SQL also. No C# or VBA needs to get written for this (unless you want a macro that saves a copy of the file on the network share whenever the user saves changes)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That's true, but in this case it's difficult for me (or even impossible). On the other hand, it's my curiosity. :)

Comment: If the person can't have access to SSMS, can you use c# to build them an exe and give that to them for them to use to do the bulk load?

Comment: ^ that would be my approach (C# code is easier to put under source control than an SSIS package, or even T-SQL scripts). Works nicely, and could be implemented as a Windows Service with a `FileSystemWatcher` ...user wouldn't even need to do anything, "just save it *there*". Look into the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace.

Comment: @CaiusJard  it'll be a solution, but I thought it is possible in VBA as well, so I wrote this post.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks, I'll try.

Comment: What do you think about solution like: VBA Macro creates the csv file, then starts the c# program with parameters (csv path) and this app do save to database (similar code what is in my post)?

Comment: You could also consider the granddaddy of all bulk insert tools -- `bcp`. That might obviate the need for a separately written program (although `bcp` can be a beast to work with if the input isn't exactly to its liking).

Comment: If you want to do it from vba all the methods I know of require the sql server to have rule read access to the data file and then running a special sql query that instructs the sql server to read and load the file.

Comment: If you can do it from c# you don't need to create a csv first as c# can read the excel file directly

Comment: @CaiusJard, Can I do it directly, even if the file is in use? I don't want to force the user to save and close the file.

Comment: Not to resurrect an old post but the fastest import of bulk xml data to sql server I've seen is using VB or C# xmlReader() to shred an xml to the Datatable object and then passing the Datatable to the SqlBulkCopy() function. Yes, I know OP isn't talking XML.....I'd love access to that object and function in VBA because I don't have access to VB or C#. Fancy xml libraries, DOM objects, SAX readers, XSLT transforms before import, bulk inserts, C++ programs etc haven't come close. I don't know why, and I may be missing something but it's just my experience.